# Axios/Vue - JSON numbers null

Tags: json, express, vue.js, axios

I'm working on a Vue frontend/Express backend application and am having an issue with a numbers in a JSON response 'arriving' at the frontend as null.

server:

```
db.boards.getUserBoards(user.user_id).then((boards) => {
            let userBoards = [];
            if (boards) userBoards = boards;
            user.boards = userBoards;
            const token = jwt.sign(JSON.stringify(user), config.secret);
            res.json({ message: 'Token granted', token, user });
```

Where `boards` is an array such as:

```
"boards": [
        {
            "board_id": 1,
            "name": "test"
        }
    ]
```

This works fine in postman (that's where the above was directly copied from), but the response in my client application has a null value
[see response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RlcAp.png). It seems to only affect the numerical values within the boards array, as the user object has an numerical id field that makes it across without issue.

client:

```
 Axios.post(`${api}/api/stuff`, credentials)
  .then(({data}) => { console.log(data) })
```

What am I missing?!

Comment: It works here. You must be returning a different `boards` object.

Comment: Is your `Axios` incidentally or accidentally spelt with a capital A?

Comment: @acdcjunior I don't seem to be, as I said I can get back the expected response by querying through postman with the same params (have also stepped through the response method and verified the boards array was correct).

Comment: @RuChernChong - Probably accidental

Comment: Maybe you have an axios interceptor somewhere changing the data. Check the network tab, if the data comes correctly from the server.

Comment: @acdcjunior I was wrong, it's something to do with Vuex (in my client example, after the log statement I was dispatching it to be saved in the store). For some reason unbeknown to me, it all falls apart if the property name has an underscore. If I change it to boardId, it saves it (although, it saves it as boardid - [removes the case]), which is confusing me a bit... Any ideas? (sorry am quite new to vue/vuex as you can probably tell)

Comment: The case change is a postgres thing, please disregard. I'm still a bit confused by the issue with the underscore though :S